# Tinimce 4 image upload throwing HTTP Error: 404

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4, image-upload

I'm using tinymce 4 with image upload from example and after selecting picture to upload I'm getting "HTTP Error: 404" message.

I've tested example postAcceptor.php with posting image file and it works.
On result of posting image I'm getting that JSON response:

> {"location":"/home/mylogin/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/projects/projectname/img/gallery/422.jpg"}

Is that correct with those extra slashes?
My code for init:

```
      tinymce.init({
            selector: 'textarea.content',
            plugins: 'image code',
            toolbar: 'undo redo | link image | code',
            // enable title field in the Image dialog
            image_title: true,
            automatic_uploads: true,

            images_upload_url: 'postAcceptor.php',
            images_upload_base_path: '/img/gallery/',
            images_upload_credentials: true,

            file_picker_types: 'image',

            // and here's our custom image picker
            file_picker_callback: function(cb, value, meta) {
                var input = document.createElement('input');
                input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
                input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');
                input.onchange = function() {
                    var file = this.files[0];

                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                    reader.onload = function () {
                        var id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
                        var blobCache =  tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
                        var base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1];
                        var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, base64);
                        blobCache.add(blobInfo);
                        cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
                    };
                };

                input.click();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

The JSON you are returning sure looks like the location on the server's hard drive.  The location gets turned into the `src` attribute for the image so it needs to be the URL that would allow the browser to fetch the image via the web server.

Comment: Still the same. Changed it to normal URL and now I get:
{"location":"http:\/\/localhost\/projectname\/img\/gallery\/422.jpg"}

Comment: What ends up in the editor for the image src when its processed?  You typically would not include the protocol or host name in the return value.

Comment: What you return needs to be a valid URL.  If what you are returning is not useable by the browser you need to change what you are returning.

Answer (score 1):

404 was caused because of

```
images_upload_url: 'postAcceptor.php',
```

I've changed it to

```
images_upload_url: './js/tinymce/postAcceptor.php',
```

Worked like a charm..